# Jquery hide elements on mouseout()

Tags: jquery, hide, mouseover, show, mouseout

I've just started learning Jquery and I was lucky enough to get something to work.
My first code was to create a "Dim the light" effect  when a button is pressed and "Show the light" when the light is out. That part is working quite fine.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dimlight").click(function(){
    $("#overlay").fadeIn();
    $(".dimlight").hide();
    $(".showlight").show();
  });
  $(".showlight").click(function(){
    $("#overlay").fadeOut();
    $(".dimlight").show();
    $(".showlight").hide();
  });
});
```

Now I wanted to take it a step further. I'd like to hide any visible button (.showlight or .dimlight) on mouseout. Basically, the active button should only be visible when the user hovers the player (#player div).  Now I tried doing it, but it didn't work. I suspect that the syntax is wrong. It sure looks very childish, sorry guys. It's my first attempt and I'd like to learn by doing.

Here's the extended code that doens't work.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".dimlight").click(function(){
        $("#overlay").fadeIn();
        $(".dimlight").hide();
        $(".showlight").show();
      });
      $(".showlight").click(function(){
        $("#overlay").fadeOut();
        $(".dimlight").show();
        $(".showlight").hide();
      });
       $("#player").mouseover(function(){
        if ($('#overlay').is(':hidden')) {
                $('.dimlight').show();
            } else {
                $('.showlight').show();
            }
      }).mouseout(function() {  

        if ($('.dimlight').is(':hidden')) {
                $('.showlight').hide();
            } else {
                $('.dimlight').hide();
            }
      });
    });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

He're the html:

```
  <div id="videoplayer_two-col">  
    <span class="dimlight" title="Baisser la lumi&egrave;re">Baisser la lumi&egrave;re</span>
     <span class="showlight" title="Alumer la lumi&egrave;re">Alumer la lumi&egrave;re</span>  

    <video id="player" width="633" height="320" poster="assets/components/ME/media/echo-hereweare.jpg" volume="0.5" controls preload="none">
      <!-- MP4 source must come first for iOS -->
      <source type="video/mp4" src="assets/components/ME/media/echo-hereweare.mp4" />
       <object width="633" height="320" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="assets/components/ME/build/flashmediaelement.swf">       
          <param name="movie" value="assets/components/ME/build/flashmediaelement.swf" /> 
          <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />                
          <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=assets/components/ME/media/media/echo-hereweare.mp4" />         
          <!-- Image fall back for non-HTML5 browser with JavaScript turned off and no Flash player installed -->
          <img src="assets/components/ME/media/echo-hereweare.jpg" width="640" height="360" alt="Here we are" 
            title="No video playback capabilities" />
      </object>     
    </video>
```

Comment: Where is the `#overlay` element?

Comment: If you have only one `.dimlight` and `.showlight` element consider using ID's rather than classes!

Answer (score 1):

```
//document ready shorthand
$(function(){

  //consolidate jquery object creation, (every $ makes a new jQuery object)
  var dimlight  = $(".dimlight"),
      showlight = $(".showlight"),
      overlay   = $("#overlay")
      isLightOn = true; //your default state

  dimlight.click(function(){
    isLightOn = false; //set state var to dimmed
    overlay.stop().fadeIn(); // use .stop() to prevent animation queue buildup
    dimlight.hide();
    showlight.show();
  });
  showlight.click(function(){
    isLightOn = false; //set state var to lighted
    overlay.stop().fadeOut(); // use .stop() to prevent animation queue buildup
    dimlight.show();
    showlight.hide();
  });

  //hover shorthand
  $("#player").hover(function(){
        if( isLightOn ) { //test state var, more efficient and less error prone
            dimlight.show();
        } else {
            showlight.show();
        }
  },function() {  
        showlight.hide(); // no need for extra logic here, 
        dimlight.hide();  // running .hide() on a hidden element does nothing        
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the well structured code. The light switch works fine with your input. But the buttons hide on player hover is still not happening. I'm digging a little deeper here. Not sure what's going on

Comment: I'm using Chrome current versions and FF 11 beta.the file is being developed locally.

Comment: I think it may be a nuance with the video tag or object tag. Sometime elements to behave properly as a wrapper. Instead inside elements trigger a mouseout on the parent. Try putting a div around the video tag, and using the hover statement on that div instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the second `if` didn't you want to check the hidden property of `#overlay` instead as you did in `mouseover`?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dimlight").click(function(){
       $("#overlay").stop()
          .removeClass('fOut').removeClass('fIn').addClass('fIn')
          .fadeIn();
       $(".dimlight").hide();
       $(".showlight").show();
    });

    $(".showlight").click(function(){
       $("#overlay").stop()
          .removeClass('fOut').removeClass('fIn').addClass('fOut')
          .fadeOut();
       $(".dimlight").show();
       $(".showlight").hide();
    });

    $("#player").mouseover(function(){
       console.log("mouseover");
       if ($('#overlay').hasClass('fOut')) {
            $('.dimlight').show();
            console.log("dim1");
       } else {
            $('.showlight').show();
            console.log("show1");
       }
    }).mouseout(function() {  
       console.log("mouseout");
       if ($('#overlay').hasClass('fOut')) {
            $('.showlight').hide();
            console.log("show2");
       } else {
            $('.dimlight').hide();
            console.log("dim2");
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thx man for the quick reply. Your take looks great, except I just tried and the buttons aren't hiding or showing. Any clue?

Comment: Don't forget something: as long as `#overlay` is fading out it will not be `:hidden`. Only when the animation complete `if($('#overlay').is(':hidden'))` will return `true`.

Comment: can you put up a js fiddle. Everything you wrote looks functional.

Comment: sorry the html has been added to the original post due to character limitations

Comment: I think it's like you said. Since fadeout doesn't qualify as hidden, I need to get around that. I think that's where the issue lies. I'll post the result once I have it figured out. thx for your help

Comment: I modified the code a little bit. I introduced two more classes to identify which fading animation is running currently. Also replaced the if statement to check the existence of the `fOut` class instead of checking the `hidden` property. It might work, try it out.

Comment: Just tried again, this thing isn't nice to us. Sorry to take so much of your time. I'm not sure if there's something else in the way

Comment: Okay, I added some debug `console.log` calls. Let's run the code and see what we got in the console! Also, you can put breakpoints by the lines and debug the code step by step. Usually F12 opens the developer window.

Comment: is it F12 in Firefox? While I'm at it let me check the script with Chrome

Comment: Yes, I'm checking in Chrome, FIrst thing I've noticed is the fact that the overlay effect doesn't work and when the player is in hover state, the showlight button replaces the default dimlight button. I'll paste the errors in a few secs

Comment: I just added the log and some warnings 'm getting in Chrome when the script is executed. Just see your code above

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we could clearly see what's going on?